# Trigger Servlet with js function

Tags: javascript, servlets

The servlet queries the database and throws data in to a file. 
This data file has to be refreshed every 10 seconds for users to view the updated information.

I need help with triggering servlet with javascript function. I am successful in getting the timeinterval method in JS but I am having issue calling the servlet.

```
var int=self.setInterval("trigger()",10000); 

function(){ 

    //Servlet queries the db and loads the data into the file. 
    trigger servlet ...??? 

    " TriggerServlet? ...... 

}
```

Comment: you have to make an ajax call. If you want to use jquery you can check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You can check an example here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830533/how-to-call-a-servlet-from-a-jquerys-ajax-function

Comment: how to fetch the response values from the servlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      var url = "servlet URL"; 
      var request = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      request.open("GET",url,true);
      request.send(null);
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                if (request.status == 200) {
                    var response = request.responseText;
                    alert(response);
                }
        }
      };
```

Comment: how to capture the response file name ?

Comment: Thanks ...I only need to return certain string as response. How to get only that?