# Jquery Ajax function is not working while calling the Servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am facing some problem while calling ajax. Can anyone look at my code and suggest something to solve my problem

```
function search(file,input){
      $.ajax({url:'/Searchandhighlight?name='+input+'&file='+file,type:"post",
              success:function(){
                 $("#bodyy").html();
              }
    });
   }
```

I am using ajax to call the servlet and servlet changes some contents of database and after success I am trying to refresh my "#bodyy" div.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what parameters file holds?

Comment: It hold filename like  "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\webapps\data\Airline Ticketing\Italian VAT\hello.txt"

Comment: And 'input' hold String from textbox

Comment: ok...can u try below code and let us know whether success is getting printed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly let us know what file variable holds.

Normally Ajax call with parameters goes like this. `dataType` depends on what kind of response you are expecting.

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Searchandhighlight",                
                dataType: "json",
                data: {"name" : input, "file" : file},
                success:function(data){
                    if(data){
                        alert("success");
                    }
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert('failed');
                } 

            })
```

Comment: Its not calling servlet at all

Comment: I tried to print some values before ajax call its working fine but it will stuck at the ajax call

Comment: plz pass data hard coded to see if it's calling the servlet or not. Like for {"Name" : "person", "file": "TBD"} and test else I am doubting that URL is not pointing to right place.

Comment: Hey i am printing some hello string to let to know servlet is called or not. But its not printing hello string,means Servlet is not called.

Comment: ok please go through this link, check your servlet and get it woking .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830533/how-to-call-a-servlet-from-a-jquerys-ajax-function

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my issue by following code

```
    function search(file,input){
      if(input != "") {
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "/Searchandhighlight?name=" + input + "&file=" + file, true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            window.location.reload();
          }
       }
        xmlhttp.send(null);
      }
   }
```